# Adding value into jlist java from mongodb

Tags: java, arrays, mongodb, jlist

I am trying to list down all the database into jlist, its working fine only the problem I can't list down into JLIST.

```
      private void dblist() throws UnknownHostException {
           MongoClient mongo = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
           java.util.List<String> dbs = mongo.getDatabaseNames();

           for (String a : dbs) {
                 System.out.println(a); // here i am already getting value 
                                        // just need to add into jlist 
                 System.out.println(a);

                 jlist.add(a); // adding value into Jlist but its giving 
                               // me error 
           }
      }
  }
```

[image: System.out.println(a) result]

Comment: `jlist` isn't assigned in your question. Please try to show a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this to convert it?;

```
String[] x = new String[dbs.size()];
JList<String> list = new JList<>(dbs.toArray(x));
```

Update:

Can you try this please;

```
yourJlist = new JList(dbs.toArray());
```

Update 2:

This code is working why dont you try like this;

```
MongoClient mongo = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
MongoCursor<String> dbs = mongo.listDatabaseNames().iterator();
while(dbs.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(dbs.next());
}
```

Comment: still giving me a error , java.lang.NullPointerException @MuratGüner

Comment: error is no longer but list appears to be blank @MuratGüner

Comment: i updated the mongoDB driver now its working but question is still there how i can add into jlist . Thank you brother for helping me :) its giving me same result as with old drivers.  the result that showing  here System.out.println(dbs.next()); i want to show into jlist  @MuratGüner

Comment: yourJlist = new JList(dbs.toArray()); this should work now mate. By the way you are welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

i have solved it so in future if anyone look for this question they can refer to this answer.

using mongodb java driver 3.4.2

mongodb to java  jlist

```
  try{
    String host=hname.getText();
    String port=spport.getValue().toString();
    Integer pt = Integer.valueOf(port);                         
        try (MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(new 
        ServerAddress(host, pt),            
                MongoClientOptions.builder()
                        .serverSelectionTimeout(2000)
                        .build())) {
            DB db = mongoClient.getDB( jlist.getSelectedValue().toString());
            DBbtn.setText("DB Connected");
            DBbtn.setBackground (new Color(109,184,0));
            DBbtn.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
            Set<String> colls = db.getCollectionNames();

            DefaultListModel listModel = new DefaultListModel();
            colls.stream().map((s) -> {
                listModel.addElement(s);
                return s;
            }).forEach((s) -> {
                System.out.println(s);
            });
            collectionss.setModel(listModel); // collectionss is jlist name 
        }

   } catch (Exception e) {
   }
```

insert from java jlist to MongoDb

```
 try{        
        String logid="Log-"+logname.getText();
        JList dataList=(loglist);
        int sixe=dataList.getModel().getSize();
    ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList();
    for (int i = 0; i <sixe; i++) {
    arrayList.add(dataList.getModel().getElementAt(i));
     server.total.setText("Total Log-"+i);

    }
    System.out.println(arrayList);
    Iterator itr = arrayList.iterator();
     String host=hname.getText();
    String port=spport.getValue().toString();                     
     MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(asList( new ServerAddress(host+":"+port)),
                                     singletonList(MongoCredential.createCredential(uname.getText(),
                                                                                    dbname.getText(),
                                                                                    pass.getText().toCharArray())),
                                     MongoClientOptions.builder().serverSelectionTimeout(2000).build());

       DB db = mongoClient.getDB( jlist.getSelectedValue().toString());
       DBCollection bookCollection = 
       db.getCollection(collectionss.getSelectedValue().toString());
        BasicDBObject doc = new BasicDBObject(logid, arrayList);
        bookCollection.insert(doc);
        server.consolelog.setText("INFO: Data is inserted succsesfully");

         }catch(Exception e){
          server.consolelog.setText(e.toString());
         }
```